# If E[X] > E[Y] , then p(X >Y) =1

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X, Y be random variables. The statement: If E[X] > E[Y] , then p (X >Y) =1 I believe is false.
because let us consider the following distributions:

For X:

P(X = 0) = 0.4,
P(X = 1) = 0.6

For Y:

P(Y = 0) = 0.2,
P(Y = 1) = 0.8

the expectation of X and Y is:

E[X] = (0 * 0.4) + (1 * 0.6) = 0.6

E[Y] = (0 * 0.2) + (1 * 0.8) = 0.8

it follows that E[X]<E[Y] but not always Y>X.

Could you give me some feedback if I am on the right track. thanks.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: If $P(x>y)=1$ then $E(x)>E(y)$ is true, but the converse isn't always true.

Comment: Nice simple example :)

Answer (score 0):

You are on a good track. For an intuitive example, you can also think about two classes after an examination, and $X$ (resp. $X$) is the grade of a student selected at random in the first (resp. second) class.

$E(X)>E(Y)$ means that the first class has a better average than the second one. Does it mean that every student in the first class had a better grade than every student in the second one? Obviously no. You can easily construct a counter-example from that.

Answer (score -1):

$(x, y) = (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)$

$P(0, 0) = 0.08$
$P(0, 1) = 0.32$
$P(1, 0) = 0.12$
$P(1, 1) = 0.48$

$P(X < Y) > P(Y > X)$ & $E(X) < E(Y)$